# how to trigger input with directive in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to fake input with angularjs. Here is the plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/N367um2YFjs2mV1KVUWw?p=preview

```
 $scope.change=function(){
   var e = document.getElementById("test");
   var $e = angular.element(e);
   $e.triggerHandler('focus');
   e.value = "ala";
   $e.triggerHandler('input');      
 }
```

I want to use a directive to fake that input. I've already make a function inside the controller to fake the input. And this function is triggered by ng-click in the button. Now I want to implement the function inside the directive so that when the directive is loaded it could fake the input for me. I've tried but the directive is not changing the model in the controller. And I know there's one way to do it, which needs to pass in the ng-model into the directive. But I'm wondering whether there's better solutions to it?

Comment: Passing ngModel in via scope: { whatever: '=ngModel' } is probably going to be the cleanest, most straightforward way to do this

Comment: @KevinF but I want the directive to be generic, and If I'm passing in the ngmodel into the directive it would be limited to my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `compile` method of the directive. There you can get the text of the directive before you replace it with the button markup.

Then you can also use the attributes of the directive to specify the target of your fake input.

The return of compile is the `postLink` method where you can attach the click event to your button. If you want to run the fake event automatically just add the code directly in this `link` method.

Please have a look at the updated plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3RKiNP7wOH3Cb7voptT8?p=preview) or below (same code).

```js
var app = angular.module('mgcrea.ngStrapDocs', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'mgcrea.ngStrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
});

'use strict';

angular.module('mgcrea.ngStrapDocs')

.controller('TypeaheadDemoCtrl', function($scope, $templateCache, $http) {

  $scope.selectedState = '';
  $scope.states = function(){
    return ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
}
  $scope.selectedIcon = '';
  $scope.icons = [
    {value: 'Gear', label: '<i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Gear'},
    {value: 'Globe', label: '<i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Globe'},
    {value: 'Heart', label: '<i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Heart'},
    {value: 'Camera', label: '<i class="fa fa-camera"></i> Camera'}
  ];
  
  $scope.change=function(){
      var e = document.getElementById("test");
      var $e = angular.element(e);
       $e.triggerHandler('focus');
        e.value = "ala";
      $e.triggerHandler('input');
      
  }

  $scope.selectedAddress = '';
  $scope.getAddress = function(viewValue) {
    var params = {address: viewValue, sensor: false};
    return $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {params: params})
    .then(function(res) {
      return res.data.results;
    });
  };

})

.directive('fakeTest',['$compile', function($compile){
   return {
     restrict:'E',
     scope:{},
     compile: function(element, attrs) {
       var fakeText = element.text();
      console.log(fakeText);
      var template = '<button ng-click="triggerFake()">click dir</button>';
      
      return function postLink(scope,element,attrs){
        element.replaceWith($compile(template)(scope));
        scope.triggerFake = function() {
          //console.log('clicked', attrs.target);
          var e = document.getElementById(attrs.target); //"test");
          var $e = angular.element(e);
           $e.triggerHandler('focus');
            e.value = fakeText;
           $e.triggerHandler('input');
           //$scope.$digest();
        }
      };
     }
   }
  
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mgcrea.ngStrapDocs">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/styles/libs.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/styles/docs.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-sanitize.min.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
    <script src="//mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.js" data-semver="v2.2.4"></script>
    <script src="//mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.js" data-semver="v2.2.4"></script>
    <script src="//mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/docs/angular-strap.docs.tpl.js" data-semver="v2.2.4"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<div class="bs-docs-section" ng-controller="TypeaheadDemoCtrl">

  <div class="page-header">
    <h1 id="typeaheads">Typeaheads <a class="small" href="//github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js" target="_blank">typeahead.js</a>
    </h1>
    <code>mgcrea.ngStrap.typeahead</code>
  </div>


  <h2 id="typeaheads-examples">Examples</h2>
  <p>Add quick, dynamic typeahead functionality with any form text input.</p>

  <div class="callout callout-danger">
    <h4>Plugin dependency</h4>
    <p>Selects require the <a href="#tooltips">tooltip module</a> and <a href="//github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/helpers/parse-options.js" target="_blank">parseOptions helper</a> module to be loaded.</p>
  </div>

  <h3>Live demo <a class="small edit-plunkr" data-module-name="mgcrea.ngStrapDocs" data-content-html-url="typeahead/docs/typeahead.demo.html" data-content-js-url="typeahead/docs/typeahead.demo.js" ng-plunkr data-title="edit in plunker" data-placement="right" bs-tooltip></a></h3>
  <pre class="bs-example-scope">$scope.selectedState = "{{selectedState}}";
$scope.states = {{states}};

$scope.selectedIcon = "{{selectedIcon}}";
$scope.icons = "{{icons}}";

$scope.selectedAddress = "{{selectedAddress}}";
</pre>
  <div class="bs-example" style="padding-bottom: 24px;" append-source>
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> State</label>
        <input id="test" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedState" bs-options="state for state in states()" placeholder="Enter state" bs-typeahead>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Icon</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedIcon" data-min-length="0" data-html="1" data-auto-select="true" data-animation="am-flip-x" bs-options="icon as icon.label for icon in icons" placeholder="Enter icon" bs-typeahead>
      </div>
      <button ng-click="change();">click</button>
      <fake-test target="test">ala</fake-test>
      <hr>
      <!-- Using an async data provider -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Address <small>(async via maps.googleapis.com)</small></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedAddress" data-animation="am-flip-x" bs-options="address.formatted_address as address.formatted_address for address in getAddress($viewValue)" placeholder="Enter address" bs-typeahead>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

  </body>

</html>
```